# Eigenvalue of symmetric matrix with rational coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I'm looking for a 2×2 symmetric matrix with rational coefficients, such as √2 is eigenvalue.
My idea is to find a 2×2 symmetric matrix such as 2 is eigenvalue, and then take the square root of this matrix.
However, I get some troubles because the square root matrix is not with rational coefficients...

Bonus: Can you prove that √3 is never an eigenvalue for a 2×2 symmetric matrix with rational coefficients? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Find a $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix of rational elements with eigenvalue $\sqrt2$.
> - Prove that a $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix of rational elements can't have eigenvalue $\sqrt3$.

Consider a $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\c&b\end{pmatrix}$$
with $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Q}$.

For it to have $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue,
\begin{align*}
(a-\lambda)(b-\lambda)-c^2&=0\\
\lambda^2-(a+b)\lambda+ab-c^2&=0\\
\lambda&=\frac{(a+b)\pm\sqrt{(a-b)^2+4c^2}}2\\
\text{Now}\qquad a+b&=0 &(\because \sqrt 2\text{ is one of the roots})\\
\text{or}\qquad a&=-b\\
\Rightarrow\sqrt{a^2+c^2}&=\sqrt2\end{align*}
Choose $a=\pm1$, $b=\mp1$, $c=1$
so that the matrix becomes
$$\begin{pmatrix}\pm1&1\\1&\mp1\end{pmatrix}$$
As for getting $\lambda=\sqrt3$, $\sqrt{a^2+c^2}=\sqrt3$, put $a\rightarrow \sqrt3\sin\theta$ and $b\rightarrow \sqrt3\cos\theta$. Both $a$ and $b$ can't be rational together since sine and cosine don't become $\pm\frac1{\sqrt3}$ together but do $\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}$. I believe that a rigorous reason can be got by drawing lines cutting graphs of sine and cosine. Try yourself!

Comment: Thank you very much! ;)